# Permission for adding sys_category in TYPO3

Tags: permissions, typo3, backend, categories

Is that right, that only admins can manage system categories (sys_catogory) in TYPO3 7.6 ?

I enabled all permissions for a user group, but the root entry under 'list' keeps empty !

Comment: Non-admin can also manage sys_category records. Be sure to give access both to listing and modify, and also to the page where the records are. Also, unmark Category Mounts if any is marked. And please verify again if the user is in the group.

Comment: And notice that non-admins can't store records on the uppest root of TYPO3.

Comment: How can I store sys_category not on the uppest root of TYPO3?

Answer (score 0):

Only admins may change records in the root of the tree. If you placed the categories there, then normal users cannot edit them.

But you can simply move them into a sysfolder below the root, and normal users with write access to that page can edit them.

Comment: I didn't know, that I can cut and paste categories to a page because the section 'Category' was never presented/visible. Thx for the advice.